# Changing the size of a <div> with the value of fetched data

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am fetching data from an api and display some props of them using mapping and I want to change the width of the  accordingly with the value of the props.

```
<h5>
    <span className="viewcount" ref={boxSize}>
    {`View Count: ${item.statistics.viewCount}`}</span>
</h5>
```

For example, this is a prop called "viewcount" from the api item, and I want the width of this component to be 200px when the viewcount prop is a number of 200.
How can I acheive it?

P.S.: I'm using react.

Comment: Just add `<span ... style={{width: item.statistics.viewCount}}>` :)

Comment: Try changing your ${item.statistics.viewCount} to ${item?.statistics?.viewCount}

Answer (score 0):

```html
150 is the default width
<h5>
    <span className="viewcount" ref={boxSize} style={{width: item.statistics.viewCount===200 ? 200: 150}}>
    {`View Count: ${item.statistics.viewCount}`}</span>
</h5>

OR if you want to always set the value of viewCount as the width

<h5>
    <span className="viewcount" ref={boxSize} style={{width: item.statistics.viewCount}}>
    {`View Count: ${item.statistics.viewCount}`}</span>
</h5>
```